# Prevent blank space in pdf pages (DomPdf)

Tags: php, html, laravel-blade

I don't want to leave blank spaces or leave only the minimum possible in pdf.
I noticed that the tag is only inserted on the page when all its content fits on the page, otherwise it advances to the next page.
I have using DOMPDF lib to generate this pdf.

[image: Pdf sample]
[image: Blade component]

Comment: Please [do not post images of code or error messages](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - post as text here

Answer (score 1):

You can give the PDF width and height and remove the margins to move it up.

```
@page {size: 600px 900px; margin:0!important; padding:0!important}
```